# series expansion unpredictably dividing by leading coefficient

Tags: series-expansion

When expanding the simple expression

```
expr = y^3
```

as a series in x, with

```
expand = y -> Sum[Subscript[y, j] x^j, {j, 1, 20}];
```

The behaviour of SeriesCoefficient and Series are unpredictable, for instance:

```
coeff11 = SeriesCoefficient[expr /. expand,{x,0,11}];
coeff12 = SeriesCoefficient[expr /. expand,{x,0,12}];
```

Then `coeff11` is of polynomial form, but `coeff12` has an overall `Subscript[y, 1]^3` factored out, and many compensating divisions. So the result is correct but unnecessarily complicated:

```
LeafCount/@{coeff11, coeff12, Simplify[coeff11],Simplify[coeff12]}
(* {103, 409, 92, 111} *)
```

On the other hand using `Series` instead, it remains explicitly polynomial up to and including order 12, and from order 13 on it again factors out the leading term, not just at order 13 but starting at order 7.

Is this a bug? is there a way to prevent this? Or a version in which this doesn't happen?
I'm using

```
$Version
(* "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)
```

(The reason I ask is that I want to do a series expansion of a more complicated expression to a high order, and want to limit the growth of complexity as much as possible, as this is the bottleneck in a computation.)

Comment: Don't use `Subscript`, try `expand = y -> Sum[ y[j] x^j, {j, 1, 20}]`instead!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann that didn't help, it gives the same for `SeriesCoefficient`, and for `Series` it starts factoring and dividing one order earlier! (of course the `LeafCount` does go down a bit but just because y[1] has one less leaf than Subscript[y,1])

Comment: In Mathematica v12 (windows 64bit) I get polynomials for coeff11 and coeff12.